# Android PayPal In-App Integration for upgrade to premium

Tags: android, paypal

I am using Ads in my App and also I am providing an option for users to upgrade via PayPal android api for Ad-Free app.

I could successfully integrate PayPal api for checkout in my app, but not getting how to tell to my app that this user has upgraded already/Now.

I want user to get ad-free app even after they re-installed the app.

Do I need to use my own server for tracking all upgrades or any other best practice is available.

Kindly help me out. Your reply is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This will likely be against the TOS. As far as I know, you can only accept "donations" through other methods and not even that is clear. I have an app that accepted donations through paypal and afterwards I sent emails to those "donators" with an unlock code to remove the advertising. That didn't seem to break any terms of service, but I wouldn't write anything saying **explicitly** that the payment outside of google waller will give them an add free version.

> "Google has been pressuring applications and mobile game developers to
>   use its costlier in-house payment service, Google Wallet for quite
>   some time. Now Google warned several developers in recent months that
>   if they continued to use other payment methods — such as PayPal, Zong
>   and Boku — their apps would be **removed from Google Play**. The move is
>   seen as a way to cut costs for Google by using their own system."

[Source](http://www.reuters.com/article/2012/03/08/us-google-idUSBRE8271CJ20120308)

Comment: Thanks Mayhem, I found MobiUcare one of the popular android App is using paypal checkout for upgrade to premium option.
"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobiucare.client"

can you please give me an idea on what is the number of donations we can expect out of 70K users?

Comment: Take your chances if you want, thought I'd give you a warning anyway